# Switching NSWindows

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

I have two `NSWindows`, both with an `NSPanel` in them. I want to switch windows when a button is pressed. How can this be done? I don't need the old window any more so I just want to show the new one.

Comment: You want to change focus from one window to the other?  Or perhaps animate the contents of one window into the other?  Be more precise.

Comment: "You want to change focus from one window to the other" - Yes, exactly that. Sorry :)

Comment: If you want to remove the “old” window from the screen, you can send it the `close` message or the `orderOut:` message.

Comment: What do you mean, you have an NSPanel inside of each NSWindow? Are you adding them as child windows? If so, what for? And how is the child window (if that is what you're doing) relevant to the switching-windows problem? And why do you want to hide the former window and not simply show the new window, either by itself or as a sheet? Showing one window and hiding another is highly irregular in Mac apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus the second window, simply call:

```
[window2 makeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: Hi, I'm doing this but nothing happens and the old window stays in place: http://pastie.org/5375952

Comment: @PixelBitAppsLtd: You can't create a window with `init`—the resulting window will have no frame rectangle and thus be unusable. Use one of the initializers listed in the NSWindow documentation.

Comment: @PeterHosey I tried this, but still no luck - the window does not change at all: http://pastie.org/5376517

Comment: OK, would this be easier; could I just create a nib with an NSPanel in it and add it as a 'subview' to the NSWindow? How can I do this? (this is my first Mac app - I'm used to iOS Development) :-)

Comment: @PixelBitAppsLtd: No; windows are not views in Cocoa. You could do a child window, but that's probably not actually what you want (then again, you haven't really said what you're trying to do). Most probably, you should just make a nib with a view in it and add that view as a subview.